# Changing specified cell color based on click on another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to know how to change color of specified cells when I click on a certain cell in google sheet? Like for example, if I click on cell containing value "fruits" then all the cells having values of either apple or banana or grape get colored.

I tried conditional formatting but couldn't find a way using that.

Comment: Hey did any of the solutions given below work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Since you added the `google-apps-script` tag I assumed that you are ok with accomplishing this using a script.

You can try the following code:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var fruits = ["Orange", "Apple", "Watermelon"];
  var clothing = ["Shirt", "Shoes", "Jeans"];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  switch(range.getA1Notation())
  {
    case "E2":
    colorSet(ss, fruits, "red");
    break;

    case "E3":
    colorSet(ss, clothing, "blue");
    break;
  }
}

function colorSet(spreadsheet, f, color)
{
  for (var i=0; i<f.length; i++)
  {
    var data = spreadsheet.createTextFinder(f[i]).findAll();
    for(var x=0; x<data.length; x++)
    {
      data[x].setBackground(color);
    }
  }
}
```

Basically every time a user clicks either cell E2 or E3, it will recognize what kind of values you have in column A and set the color based on that.

#### References:

- [setBackground(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)
- [TextFinder: findAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findall)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way of making formatting changes on following the mouse in Google Sheets. What you can do is have a cell as reference, maybe a dropdown, in which you select a value, and all equal values are highlighted. In this case, I put "Text is exactly" and `=$C$1` which is my cell:

[image]

Whenever you change that cell, the highlighting will update